# How web sites get and put on their sites what we type in search engines

Tags: seo, web

When we find in search engines, the text we typed is seen in result list with some links as it is. But the matter is, when we go to those sites, the same text is also there, but saying 'not found'.(For example, lets say, we type 'best software to doSomeThing' in google, the search results shows results including what we typed. When we go to some links listed in search results, those sites also have the same text 'best software to doSomeThing-Not found or saying what ever..' the amazing thing is, some sites is not relevant to what we find. that means if we find a software, some sites on tourism,drugs also says about our software)

I want to know how those sites catch what the search engines finds or what we type in search engines?
Is it something done with Javascript or any other methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `HTTP_REFERER` and parse the query string looking for `q=`

Answer (score 1):

these can be done using several ways

1. you can use query string parameter which is appended with url of a page u you want to visit
2. or you can use hidden fields in webpage,like view state,control state

hope this helps...

Edit:

here is the link,that shows basic functionality of query string..
http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/aspnet-query-strings-client-si

edit 2: check

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getQuery%28%29

and this ones too

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I m familiar with J2EE not Asp :( would you see any other j2ee related good articles?